# godaddy database stores Mysql time only in 12 hour format

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

when i execute the same query on my local `phpmyadmin` and the `godaddy phpmyadmin` the time stored is different.

locally i get the `24-hr` format and on the online server i get `12-hr` format

**here it the query i used to create the table:**

```
ALTER TABLE `data_tab` ADD `dateupdated` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `name_column` ;
```

No other column has any date or time dataType.

**Here it the insert query i used on both:(I used the phpMyadmin insert UI inerface)**

```
INSERT INTO `dbname`.`data_tab` (`dateupdated`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

what i get on the server is :**2015-01-20 09:01:36**

and on local wamp server i get: **2015-01-20 21:31:45**

There is no time Zone issue but as the time is same, the issue is of the 12/24 hr format.

I am not inserting the time progamatically using the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" to insert the time.

How to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following variables value in MySQL.

```
SET GLOBAL datetime_format ='%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s';
SET GLOBAL time_format ='%h:%i:%s';
```

Comment: i used the following article http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/ but still no luck..the time on the server is offset by 5:50 hrs or so

Comment: getting this: " Variable 'datetime_format' is a read only variable"..i think it is a timezone problem after all..it just so happened that the server was ahead 12 hrs so i thought it was a format problem..sever must have been exactly on the opposite site of the world..

Comment: No its not timezone issue its date/time format problem... ask your service provider to do so.. or you can change data-time accordingly in php code.

Comment: yes...to be save i have decided to modify my php code so it is cross server compatible and safe if my provider messes up..thanks